# Execute a method of accepted generic Type, inside a partially abstract class - Java

Tags: java, android, generics, generic-programming

### My Situation:

I have 3 Classes (For my Android-App) who extend a partially abstract Class, where i define and implement the function: deleteObject(); This Function accept a generic Type T.

```
public abstract class GenericDatabaseManager<T> {
    public void deleteObject (T inObject) {

        // want to execute the function inObject.getId(); 
        // who is defined in the Workout, Exercise and the User
        // class
        
    }
    
    ...
}

public class WorkoutManager extends GenericDatabaseManager<Workout> {
    deleteObject(Workout);
}

public class ExerciseManager extends GenericDatabaseManager<Exercise> {
    deleteObject(Exercise);
}

public class UserManager extends GenericDatabaseManager<User> {
    deleteObject(User);
}
```

### Question:

How can i execute the

```
inObject.getId();
```

who is defined in the Workout, Exercise and the User class inside my

```
deleteObject(T inObject);
```

?

I hope my question is understandable and i'm happy about every answer.
Maybe (I'm optimistic) someone can and will help me :-)

Best regards

Comment: You'll need to cast it. Possibly define an interface and put a bound on your generic type parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't placed any upper bound on `T`, so the compiler doesn't know that it's an object that has a `getId()` method.

You can create an interface:

```
interface HasId {
    public int getId();
}
```

Then restrict `T` to be a `HasId`:

```
public abstract class GenericDatabaseManager<T extends HasId> {
```

And your `Workout`, etc. classes can implement `HasId`.

Then the compiler has enough information to know that whatever `T` winds up being, it knows there is at least a `getId()` method that can be called.